# R summarize predicted value by groups from multiple datasets

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, mice

I ran mice function and generated 3 mice imputed datasetes.

I have a nonstandard model that is not supported by `with` function so. I used this example and `pool_parameters` below to pool the model estimates based on Rubin's Rules.

```r
models <- lapply(1:imputed_data$m, function(i) {
      mixed_model(
        cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period,
        random = ~ 1 | herd,
        data = complete(imputed_data, action = i),
        family = binomial
      )
    })
pool_parameters(models)
```

I am unable to use `emmeans` from the mice object after fitting model on multiple datasets because I have a nonstandard model that is not supported by `emmeans`. So I use the `predicted value` and create a dataset as shown below.

```r
imp x y_pred

1 4 -2.918
1 4 -2.181
1 1  1.335
1 3  0.119
1 1 -2.559
1 1  1.906
1 3 -0.236
1 1 -1.745
1 4  0.510
1 3  2.020
1 3 -2.475
1 1  0.164
2 2  1.498
2 2 -0.820
2 2 -2.626
2 4  2.248
2 1  2.227
2 1 -1.975
2 4 -2.059
2 4 -2.865
2 4  0.673
2 2  1.311
2 2  2.710
2 3 -2.923
3 4  0.792
3 1  0.104
3 4 -1.116
3 3 -2.322
3 2 -1.570
3 4  2.316
3 1 -1.358
3 2 -1.138
3 3 -2.455
3 4 -0.376
3 4  0.054
3 2 -1.195
```

My goal is to create a summary estimate of `average y_pred` , and `CI` for each values in x

```
x   y_pred(average)    C.I
1   ....               ..
2   ....               ..
3   ....               ..
4   ....               ..
```

I do know how to estimate the `average y_pred = y_pred/n`, `SE = s.dev(y_pred)/n` and `C.I = average(y_pred) +/- S.E*1.96` but I am not sure how to estimate the average and C.I based on multiple mice imputed dataset for different levels of x. Also the use of Rubin's rules adds to my confusion. Any help or suggestion regarding this matter is much appreciated.